# Minimize and rearrange list

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list where I want to reduce the number of values in that list. So I order the list and try to use ranges, but I'm a bit stuck.

Code thus far:

```
ports=["1/1/1","1/1/3","2/1/5", "1/1/2", "2/1/6" ]
arange=[]
brange=[]
def test():
   for i in ports:
       num=i.split("/")
       portnum=num [-1]
       arange.append(portnum)
   portindex=i[:-1]
   arange.sort()
   for i in range(len(arange)-1):
       a, b= int (arange[i]), int (arange[i+1]) 
       if (a+1) == b:
           brange.append(portindex+arange[i]+"-"+str(b))
   print (brange)
test()
```

Output I have is:

```
['2/1/1-2', '2/1/2-3', '2/1/5-6']
```

What I really want is

```
['1/1/1-3','2/1/5-6']
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). It first groups the ports into a the defaultdict of lists, then outputs the grouped result ranges using the `minmax()` utility function.

```
from collections import defaultdict

ports = ["1/1/1", "1/1/3", "2/1/5", "1/1/2", "2/1/6"]

def minmax(numbers):
    """Returns minumum and maximum numbers in sequence"""
    return min(numbers), max(numbers)

# Group ports
d = defaultdict(list)
for port in ports:
    key, number = port.rsplit("/", 1)
    d[key].append(number)

print(["%s/%d-%d" % (k, *minmax(list(map(int, v)))) for k, v in d.items()])
# ['1/1/1-3', '2/1/5-6']
```

**Note:** `str.rsplit()` splits from the right. Specifically in this case, the first `1` delimeter from the right.

**Update**

If you want to handle missing ports, you can try this function:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

def group_ports(ports):
    result = []

    # Group ports
    port_groups = defaultdict(list)
    for port in ports:
        key, number = port.rsplit("/", 1)
        port_groups[key].append(number)

    # Go through each port group
    for port, ranges in port_groups.items():

        # Sort ranges
        sorted_range = sorted(map(int, ranges))

        # Iterate grouped consecutive numbers 
        # e.g. [1,2,3,4,6,7] -> [[1,2,3,4], [6,7]]
        for _, g in groupby(enumerate(sorted_range), key=lambda x: x[0] - x[1]):
            # Get only numbers in sequence
            sequence = list(map(itemgetter(1), g))

            # Append port strings
            # Singleton sequences will be port/number, otherwise port/min-max
            result.append(
                "%s/%d" % (port, sequence[0])
                if len(sequence) == 1
                else "%s/%d-%d" % (port, sequence[0], sequence[-1])
            )

    return result

print(group_ports(["1/1/1", "1/1/3", "2/1/5", "1/1/2", "2/1/6"]))
print(group_ports(["1/1/1", "1/1/3", "1/1/2", "1/2/1", "1/2/3", "1/2/4"]))
```

**Output:**

```
['1/1/1-3', '2/1/5-6']
['1/1/1-3', '1/2/1', '1/2/3-4']
```

Answer (score 2):

Although there are some other tidier solutions, mine is a bit different.
The others just take the min and the max, meaning if you enter:

`minify(['1/1/1','1/1/900'])`

You will get:

`['1/1/1-900']`

Which might not be what you want.

My function creates a new group as soon as two ports are furter than 1 apart from each other:

`['1/1/1', '1/1/900']`

```py
def minify(ports):
    ports.sort()
    heads = []
    tails = []
    for port in ports:
        s = port.split('/')
        heads.append('/'.join(s[:-1]))
        tails.append(s[-1])

    combined = zip(heads, tails)
    d = {}

    for i, port in enumerate(combined):
        if port[0] not in d:
            d[port[0]] = [int(port[1])]
        else:
            d[port[0]].append(int(port[1]))

    for _, typus in d.items():
        typus.sort()

    print(d)

    d_groups = {}

    for head, tails in d.items():
        d_groups[head] = []
        for tail in tails:
            tail = int(tail)
            in_group = False
            for group in d_groups[head]:
                print(tail, group)
                if tail >= group[0] and tail <= group[1]:
                    in_group = True
                    break
                elif tail > group[1] and tail == group[1] + 1:
                    in_group = True
                    group[1] += 1
                    break

            if not in_group:
                d_groups[head].append([int(tail), (tail)])

    tidy_groups = []
    for key, value in d_groups.items():
        for group in value:
            if group[0] == group[1]:
                tidy_groups.append(f'{key}/{group[0]}')
            else:
                tidy_groups.append(f'{key}/{group[0]}-{group[1]}')

    return tidy_groups
```

Comment: Hi Lu, indeed, I mentioned this in a reply on Rob's post. Even thought your code is a bit less readable it achieves almost my goal. If I use ports=["1/1/1","1/1/3","2/1/5", "1/1/2", "2/1/6" ] I got '1/1': [[1, 3]], '2/1': [[5, 6]] as output. I tried to change it a bit, but can seem to reach the notation that I really need. Which is '1/1/1-3', '2/1/5-6' And what if you get a double digit as portnumber (eg 1/1/10)?

Comment: I will tidy up my code in a bit and fix the stuff you mentioned. Thanks! :)
Update: Now everything should be working, the faulty output was actually caused by a print statement I left in there, whoops

Comment: it works and I understand what's going on, thanks for your input. A detail thought; if I use ports ["1/1/9", "1/1/10", "1/1/11"] the output will be ['1/1/10-11', '1/1/9']. But your solution works, and the complete new file to be send to the end-devices is reduces with more than 75%!

Comment: I looked into it and it looks like the problem is the .sort() function on strings of numbers, which puts 10 and 11 before 9. This obviously can be easily solved by just converting to int which is what I did and now I get the result ['1/1/9-11'] for your input. (I edited my original answer)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want:

```
ports=["1/1/1","1/1/3","2/1/5", "1/1/2", "2/1/6" ]

def minimize_list(ports):
    ports = [x.split("/") for x in ports]

    temp_new_ports = {}

    for n in ports:
        if not n[0] in temp_new_ports.keys():
            temp_new_ports[n[0]] = {}
        if not n[1] in temp_new_ports[n[0]].keys():
            temp_new_ports[n[0]][n[1]] = []

        temp_new_ports[n[0]][n[1]].append(n[2])
        temp_new_ports[n[0]][n[1]].sort()

    new_ports = []
    for key,value in temp_new_ports.items():
        for key2, value2 in value.items():
            this_entry = f"{key}/{key2}/"

            _min, _max = value2[0], value2[-1]
            if _min == _max:
                this_entry += str(_min)
            elif int(_max) - int(_min) + 1 == len(value2):
                this_entry += f"{_min}-{_max}"
            else:
                this_entry += ','.join(value2)
            new_ports.append(this_entry)

    return new_ports

print(minimize_list(ports))
```

Output:

```
['1/1/1-3', '2/1/5-6']
```

Answer (score 0):

This will achieve what you want:

```
ports = ["1/1/1","1/1/3","2/1/5", "1/1/2", "2/1/6" ]
indexes = {}
def test():
    for i in ports:
        num = i.split("/")
        portindex = i[:-1]
        if portindex not in indexes:
            indexes[portindex] = []
        indexes[portindex].append(num[-1])
    print([f"{i}{min(e)}-{max(e)}" for i, e in indexes.items()])
test()
```

This will output what you're looking for:

```
['1/1/1-3', '2/1/5-6']
```

Comment: Ok, I think understand. But what if there are some missing values in the list:
example; 
ports=["1/1/1", "1/1/3", "1/1/2", "1/2/1" , "1/2/3", "1/2/4"]
wouldn't the output be 
['1/1/1-3', '1/2/1-4]?
How can we split that up in an easy way?
['1/1/1-3', '1/2/1-2, '1/2/4']?